# Regex match a non-unique character in same string

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, textpad

Here is an example string. I have many more of these that I need to fix:

```
"måde", "answer" => "råd");
```

In this string there are 2 instances of the character å. I want find a match for the å in **råd** using regex, while ignoring the the å in **måde**.

So basically I need to find a match of an occurrence of å after `answer`.

I thought that `(?<=answer)å(?=\;)` would work, but I'm really new to this and would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

I tried asking this question before but got downvoted for some reason, so I tried to reformulate it here. I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look behinds (typically) can't be of variable length, but by using a *negative* look ahead, you tell it what *not* to match:

```
 å(?!.*answer)
```

This matches "å", but only if "answer" doesn't appear somewhere after it.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=answer.*?)å(?=.*?;)` should work (I don't think you need to escape the semicolon, but depending on your application you might need to reescape it).

Essentially: Lookaheads/Lookbehinds still "match" at the position you're at.

edit: Many regex engines (including Sublime Text 2's) don't like quantifiers in lookahead/lookbehind assertions. Use `(?<=answer).*?å.*?(?=;)` instead and search in the resulting match with a second regex.

Comment: This should work in .NET. However not all languages support quantifiers in look-ahead/look-behinds. If you can not use * in your look-ahead, just get the substring behind "answer" with (?<=answer).*(?=;) and find all matches of å in that substring with a second regular expression :)

Comment: Just tested it, and indeed Sublime Text 2 has a problem with it. Good point.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've had a similar result with `(?<=answer).*(?=;)`, but don't know how to search with a second regex

Comment: That will be difficult to do in a text editor, but easy in most scripting languages.